# Which version of Little Gold Star or the Three Fairies involved a donkey tail?

Tags: myth-identification, fairy-tales

I'm trying to find a version of [The Three Fairies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Fairies) (or it may have been a retelling of Cinderella) in which an evil sister gets a donkey tail placed on her forehead. By contrast, the kind protagonist gets a [star on her forehead](https://writinginmargins.weebly.com/home/a-star-on-her-forehead) instead.

There are versions involving donkey ears and other body parts, but the one I read specifically had a tail coming down from the sky to land on the evil sister's head, and it may have involved more than one sibling. Does anyone know of this particular version, and where it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs in the Italian [Colony of Cats](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/142/the-crimson-fairy-book/5123/the-colony-of-cats/), except for the specific detail of the sky:

> The little maid, having gratefully kissed the white paw of the old cat, set off for home; but just as she got near her mother’s house the cock crowed, and quickly she turned towards it. Immediately a beautiful golden star appeared on her forehead, crowning her glossy black hair

> She was within sight of her mother’s house when she heard in the meadow on the right, the voice of a donkey loudly braying. Quickly she turned her head towards it, and at the same time put her hand up to her forehead, where, waving like a plume, was a donkey’s tail.